# Problem compiling in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, compilation, classpath

I've been trying to compile a very simple test.clj in Clojure without any success.  I have a [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/1adda2c8053f304d#) on the [Clojure Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure) with several responses, but nothing has helped.  To quickly summarize, here is my clojure file:

```
(ns test.test
    (:gen-class))

(defn -main
    [gre]
    (println (str "Hello " gre)))
```

Basically it's the example file provided in the [Clojure documentation](http://clojure.org/compilation).

I have placed this file appropiately in `clojure/src/test/test.clj`, and should be able to compile with `(compile 'test.test)`, but I keep getting the error:

```
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified (test.clj:1)
```

which leads me to believe it is a classpath problem.  I have tried running Clojure with all the standard commands given in the [Clojure documenation](http://clojure.org/repl_and_main) as well as the latest suggestion from the thread `java -classpath .;src;classes;clojure.jar clojure.main`.

If it helps, my filesystem looks like this:

```
-+-clojure
 +-classes/
 +-+-src/
 | |-+-test/
 | | \-test.clj
 +-\-test.clj
 +-test.clj
 +-clojure.jar
```

P.S.  I am running on Vista Ultimate so it may *possibly* be a permissions problem, but I have checked the permissions and could not find anything wrong with them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Console output for compiling *test.clj* on Windows:

```
C:\clojure>dir /b/s
C:\clojure\classes
C:\clojure\src
C:\clojure\src\test
C:\clojure\src\test\test.clj

C:\clojure>java -cp c:\dev\clojure.jar;.\src;.\classes clojure.lang.ReplClojure
user=> (compile 'test.test)
test.test
user=>
```

The generated class files are in the classes directory.

Also, note that you're missing a right parenthesis in your *main*. Corrected version:

```
(ns test.test
    (:gen-class))

(defn -main
    [gre]
    (println (str "Hello " gre)))
```

Comment: Excelent!  Thank-yee greatly, it works like a charm!  Also, I'm going to edit the question because I that close-paren just was cut off from the copy/paste I did.

Comment: HI I am getting the same problem. What could be wrong? 
I tried your solution:
C:\clojure>java -cp clojure-1.0.0.jar;.\src;.\classes clojure.lang.Repl
user=> (compile 'test.test)
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified (test.clj:1)

Comment: This means that you didn't have the classes/ directory in your CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

```
 C:\clojrue\java -cp .\src;.\classes;clojure.jar 
    -Dclojure.compile.path=classes clojure.lang.Compile test.test
```