# Gen-Class does not generate a .class file

Tags: java, interface, clojure, gen-class

I'd like to use Clojure code within Java. The Clojure code itself should implement a Java-interface (`TestGenClassInterface`).

My project.clj is:

```
(defproject com.stackoverflow.clojure/tests "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Tests of Clojure test-framework."
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [instaparse "1.3.4"]]
  :source-paths      ["src/main/clojure"]
  :java-source-paths ["src/main/java"]
  :test-paths        ["src/test/clojure"]
  :java-test-paths   ["src/test/java"]
  ;:aot :all
  )
```

The Java interface looks like this:

```
package com.stackoverflow.clojure;

public interface TestGenClassInterface {

    public String addToString(String text, String appendText);

}
```

The Clojure code is:

```
(ns com.stackoverflow.clojure.testGenClass
  (:gen-class
     :name com.stackoverflow.clojure.TestGenClass
     :implements com.stackoverflow.clojure.TestGenClassInterface
     :prefix "java-"))

(def ^:private pre "START: ")

(defn java-addToString [this text post]
  (str pre text post))

(java-addToString "TexT" " :END")
```

I expected, that after running `lein compile` or "Run as Clojure-Application" in eclipse+CounterClockwise a .class file (named `TestGenClass.class`) is generated an saved within `*compile-path*` (here: target/classes/com/stackoverflow/clojure/). Unfortunately it's not.

When adding `:aot :all` to my project.clj, I get the following stacktrace:

```
Compiling com.stackoverflow.clojure.testGenClass
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol, compiling:(com/stackoverflow/clojure/testGenClass.clj:1:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6651)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5782)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$TryExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:2191)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6644)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5782)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5217)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3846)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6642)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6632)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3665)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6445)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7221)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7216)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7292)
    at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:398)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:438)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$compile$fn__5071.invoke(core.clj:5652)
    at clojure.core$compile.invoke(core.clj:5651)
    at user$eval9.invoke(form-init4595004281107083893.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6693)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7086)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:274)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:307)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol
    at clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom(RT.java:505)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:486)
    at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
    at clojure.core$map$fn__4245.invoke(core.clj:2551)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:484)
    at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
    at clojure.core$map$fn__4245.invoke(core.clj:2551)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49)
    at clojure.lang.Cons.next(Cons.java:39)
    at clojure.lang.RT.boundedLength(RT.java:1654)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:130)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
    at clojure.core$mapcat.doInvoke(core.clj:2586)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423)
    at clojure.core$generate_class.invoke(genclass.clj:164)
    at clojure.core$gen_class.doInvoke(genclass.clj:638)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1557)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:519)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:270)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.macroexpand1(Compiler.java:6552)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6630)
    ... 46 more
Compilation failed: Subprocess failed
```

Comment: Shouldn't you prefix method names with `-`?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You're right. I added the prefix to my code. But still no class file is generated.

Comment: You need to add `:aot :all` to project.clj. See `lein sample` for more info.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik adding `:aot :all` gives the error I added to my question.

Comment: Well, that sounds like you're finally compiling your namespace into a class. You have a syntax error now, coming from a symbol at a place where a collection is expected. My guess: `:implements` takes a vector, not a single symbol.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It was the missing `AOT`, the fact that `:implements` takes a vector and the missing this ( @G_A ). Can anyone of you write an answer out of it, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proximate issue you have is a missing `:aot :all` in your `project.clj` file. Without that the ahead-of-time compilation will not be attempted.

Once you put that in, you'll have the following further issues:

- you must prefix the names of the functions designated to become Java methods (default prefix is `-`);
- you must include `this` as an explicit first argument of each such method (`this` is the recommended convention, but any name is acceptable);
- you must correct your `:implements` clause: it takes a *vector* as the value, even if it has a single member.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://clojure.org/compilation

> ... the implementation functions for instance methods will always take an
>   additional first arg corresponding to the object the method is called
>   upon, called by convention 'this' here.

Try adding 'this' to each function definition.

```
(defn java-addToString [this text post]
  ...
```

Comment: Adding this did not change anything. There is also no error message shown (e.g. when running `lein compile`). It is really annoying when **nothing** happens - at least an error would be great.

Answer (score 0):

http://clojure.org/compilation mentions the compilation process makes use of

> ... *compile-path*, which must be in the classpath

The default location is a classes folder.

The second answer to Stack Overflow question [Compiling Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123662/compiling-clojure) mentions that this path is relative to the jvm startup folder.  If you did lein repl from the main project folder (the folder where project.clj lives) then creating a classes folder there should make it work.